# Append text to anchor tag having specific class

Tags: jquery, html

for this html list,

```
<ul class="buttons">
    <li class="back"><a href="#">ABCDE</a></li>
    <li class="back"><a href="#">B</a></li>
    <li class="back"><a href="#">CEDFRD</a></li>
    <li class="back"><a href="#">D</a></li>
    <li>E</li>
    <li>F</li>
    <li>G</li>
    <li>H</li>
</ul>
```

Want append text to the end of the text in anchor tag only if,

- Text in anchor tag is having lenght more than 5 chars.
- Apply to only li having back class.

How to do this using jquery?

Comment: Have you checked my answer.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the receiver function of [**`.text()`**](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to accomplish your task.

Try,

```
$('li.back a').text(function(_,text){ 
   return text + "yourNewText"; 
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/F8bhp/1/)

As per your new edit(*only if the text in anchor text is having lenght more than 5 char*) you can use,

```
$('li.back a').text(function(_,text){ 
    return (text.length > 5) ? text + "yourNewText" : text; 
});
```

### [DEMO I](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/F8bhp/2/)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
$('li.back a').append('text');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F8bhp/)**

Answer (score 3):

use `.append()`:

```
$('li.back a').append('sm text');
```